# How to return multiple strings separated by a space in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb, helper

I am using the following view helper defined in my application_helper.rb file:

```
def even_odd(index)
  if index.to_i % 2 == 0
    "left_border white"
  else
    "left_border"
  end
end
```

In my view there is a table that needs alternate classes for a grey-white pattern:

```
<td class=<%= even_odd(index) %>> <%=investment.amount %> </td>
```

This, however, only returns `left_border`, but not `left_border white`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `index` come from? You have to increase `index` by one on every iteration or nothing will happen. The best way to solve this, however, is to use `cycle` as suggested by Faisal.

Comment: index comes from a table in html code and yes it is incremented on each iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has a builtin [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) for this functionality:

```
<tr class="left_border <%= cycle(' white', '') %>"></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this, great answer. I don't need to make view helpers with this method available. I know more now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<td class="<%= even_odd(index)%>"> <%=investment.amount %> </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def even_odd(index)
 ((index.to_i % 2) == 0 ? "left_border white" : "left_border" )
end
```

kill the extra space `<%=even_odd(index)%>`

and add quotes back to your class `<td class="<%=even_odd(index) %>">`

Comment: Why does the extra space have to be killed?

Answer (score 1):

I slightly updated your method, I used ternary operator to reduce line of codes :-

```
def even_odd(index)
  ((index.to_i%2 == 0) ? "left_border white" : "left_border")
end
```

and I also want to suggest you to use interpolation for helper methods in views :-

```
<td class="<%= even_odd(index) %>"> <%=investment.amount %> </td>
```

I am not much familiar with erb templates, I used to this in haml templates. BTW I updated the answer.

Comment: String interpolation method didn't give class name

Comment: I am not much familiar with erb templates, I used to this in haml templates. BTW I updated the answer. thanks for correcting me.